# Unit Testing : Raise Event From Nested Type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, justmock

I have an Interface which has a property on another interface,

```
public interface IInnerInterface
{
    event EventHandler OnCompleted;
}

public class InnerClassImplementation : IInnerInterface
{
    public event EventHandler OnCompleted;

    private void CompletedState()
    {
        OnCompleted?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public interface IOuterInterface
{
    IInnerInterface InnerInterface { get; }
}

public class Main : IOuterInterface
{
    public IInnerInterface InnerInterface { get; }

    public bool IsOperationComplete { get; set; }

    public Main(IInnerInterface innerInterface)
    {
        InnerInterface = innerInterface;
        InnerInterface.OnCompleted += InnerInterface_OnCompleted;
    }

    private void InnerInterface_OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsOperationComplete = true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to test the Main class. One of the test case is to validate the Handler method for the event.

I tried the following code implementation to test,

```
[TestClass]
public class MainTest
{
    private Mock<IInnerInterface> _innerInterfaceMock;
    private Main _main;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _innerInterfaceMock = new Mock<IInnerInterface>();
        _main = new Main(_innerInterfaceMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OnCompleted_ShouldDoSomething()
    {
        //Act
        _main.Raise(m=>m.InnerInterface.OnCompleted+=null, new EventArgs());

        //Assert
        _main.IsOperationComplete.Should().BeTrue();

    }
}
```

I am getting the following error,

> Test method
>   Samples.MainTest.OnCompleted_ShouldDoSomething
>   threw exception:  Telerik.JustMock.Core.MockException: Unable to
>   deduce which event was specified in the parameter.
>       at Telerik.JustMock.Core.Behaviors.RaiseEventBehavior.RaiseEventImpl(Object
>   instance, EventInfo evt, Object[] args)    at
>   Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.GuardInternal(Action
>   guardedAction)    at
>   Samples.MainTest.OnCompleted_ShouldDoSomething()

Don't know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, tell me, are you using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) or are you using [JustMock](https://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx)? make up your mind and fix the tags!

Comment: I am trying to use justmock

Comment: I created a sample from the real code. As part of that I forgot to remove the namespace. On the title, I accepted the change from @quetzalcoatl

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I'm not sure, actually; I didn't make that change. I was wondering the same thing when I went back to look at the diff. Looking at the history it seems it was in the original, and then the OP replaced it with Samples -- we must have been making edits around the same time and my change overwrote his. Raajkumar feel free to switch that back, apologies.

Comment: Sure will update it.

Comment: That was truly interesting set of glitches in editing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't raise the event from your [SUT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) (Main), raise it straight from the IInnerInterface mock:

```
_innerInterfaceMock.Raise(o => o.OnCompleted+=null, new EventArgs());
```

BTW this code (which is based on yours) uses `moq` not `justmock` but your exception is `justmock` related, I assume that using both causes methods and overloads confusions, just pick one and stick with it.